# scp/sftp backup script

Tags: backup, sftp, scp

I'm looking for a simple backup solution. My hoster has provided some backup space on remote server over scp/sftp. They have supplied me a username and a password. The option of auth with a RSA/DSA key is not avaliable.

Ideally, I'd like to have a simple script that would:

```
tar | gzip | gpg | scp -uuser -ppassword my.backup.server
```

However I can't find an scp client that would accept username and password on command line and stuff to transfer on standart input.

Comment: Honestly, I'd ask them for the ability to use (and *require*) key-based authentication. More secure for you, and therefore more secure for them. If they can't/won't do it, there's other, better hosting providers out there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on windows, then WinSCP can be scripted. If you're on Linux (or Windows, too) you can find or install Expect, which can script anything interactive.